# Unable to connect to OpenVPN with iOS. Works fine with Android

Tags: vpn

I've setup my rpi3 running OpenVPN with the script from www.pivpn.io. It works fine with my Android phone (Samsung S6). It doesn't work with my iPad air, nor with an iPhone.
What can cause OpenVPN not to work with iOS devices?

Here's the config file from the iPad:

client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com 1195
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
verb 1

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- (etc, etc)

And here's the log:

2017-03-17 13:18:12 ----- OpenVPN Start -----
OpenVPN core 3.1.2 ios arm64 64-bit built on Dec 5 2016 12:50:25
2017-03-17 13:18:12 Frame=512/2048/512 mssfix-ctrl=1250
2017-03-17 13:18:12 UNUSED OPTIONS
4 [resolv-retry] [infinite]
5 [nobind]
6 [persist-key]
7 [persist-tun]
11 [verify-x509-name] [server] [name]
15 [verb] [1]

2017-03-17 13:18:12 EVENT: RESOLVE
2017-03-17 13:18:12 Contacting xx.xxx.xx.xxx:1195 via UDP
2017-03-17 13:18:12 EVENT: WAIT
2017-03-17 13:18:12 SetTunnelSocket returned 1
2017-03-17 13:18:12 Connecting to [xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com]:1195 (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) via UDPv4
2017-03-17 13:18:13 NET Internet:ReachableViaWiFi/-R t------
2017-03-17 13:18:22 Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...
2017-03-17 13:18:22 EVENT: RECONNECTING
2017-03-17 13:18:22 EVENT: RESOLVE
2017-03-17 13:18:22 Contacting xx.xxx.xx.xxx:1195 via UDP
2017-03-17 13:18:22 EVENT: WAIT
2017-03-17 13:18:42 SetTunnelSocket returned 1
2017-03-17 13:18:42 Connecting to [xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com]:1195 (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) via UDPv4
2017-03-17 13:18:52 Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...
2017-03-17 13:18:52 EVENT: RECONNECTING
2017-03-17 13:18:52 EVENT: RESOLVE
2017-03-17 13:18:52 Contacting xx.xxx.xx.xxx:1195 via UDP
2017-03-17 13:18:52 EVENT: WAIT
2017-03-17 13:18:52 SetTunnelSocket returned 1
2017-03-17 13:18:52 Connecting to [xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com]:1195 (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) via UDPv4
2017-03-17 13:19:02 Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...
2017-03-17 13:19:02 EVENT: RECONNECTING
2017-03-17 13:19:02 EVENT: RESOLVE
2017-03-17 13:19:02 Contacting xx.xxx.xx.xxx:1195 via UDP
2017-03-17 13:19:02 EVENT: WAIT
2017-03-17 13:19:02 SetTunnelSocket returned 1
2017-03-17 13:19:02 Connecting to [xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com]:1195 (xx.xxx.xx.xxx) via UDPv4
2017-03-17 13:19:12 EVENT: CONNECTION_TIMEOUT [ERR]
2017-03-17 13:19:12 EVENT: DISCONNECTED
2017-03-17 13:19:12 Raw stats on disconnect:
BYTES_OUT : 3240
PACKETS_OUT : 60
CONNECTION_TIMEOUT : 1
N_RECONNECT : 5
2017-03-17 13:19:12 Performance stats on disconnect:
CPU usage (microseconds): 52155
Network bytes per CPU second: 62122
Tunnel bytes per CPU second: 0
2017-03-17 13:19:12 EVENT: DISCONNECT_PENDING
2017-03-17 13:19:12 ----- OpenVPN Stop ----

Comment: Their [FAQ page](https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/openvpn-connect/openvpn-connect-ios-faq.html) has a lengthy list of common faults - anything there ringing any bells?

Comment: Nothing that would affect iOS but not Android.